# WSOS Identity Server Beta Releases

Tags: build, wso2, beta, wso2-identity-server

Is it possible to download Beta releases and RC releases of Identity Server?  I saw 5.1 went Beta last week and there are quite a few things I'd like to check out.

If there isn't a download, are the build / source download procedures changing much since it's a different carbon and much has moved into Github...?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out if you choose the "Releases" tab on the Github project, you can download a built copy, plus bundled source for that tag... 
https://github.com/wso2/product-is/releases